# Using Sublime Text as default e-mail editor in Thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird, sublime-text-3, sublime-text, thunderbird-addon

### 1. Briefly

I want to write my e-mail messages use external editor Sublime Text 3. But I don't know, how I can do it.

---

### 2. Example of expected behavior

For example, I get email in Thunderbird. I click to Reply → Sublime Text 3 open for me → I write my email in Sublime Text 3 → save → my text will be shown in compose Thunderbird window.

---

### 3. Did not help

1. I can find only Globs External Editor extension for solution this problem. [**I install External Editor**](https://globs.org/articles.php?lng=en&pg=2) → I click to External Editor button in Thunderbird →

[image: Globs]

new tab open for me in Sublime Text → I wrote text my e-mail → I save tab → the message will be updated in the Thunderbird compose window.

Last update External Editor [**date 2011 year**](https://globs.org/dwnld.php?lng=en&pg=2698), I think, it does not make sense to write a bug report.

---

### 4. Do not offer

1. Yes, I know, that I can copy my text into Sublime Text and paste it to Thunderbird. Please, do not offer it.